# Exit code -1 with while:True block

Tags: python

So I ran across an interesting problem in python today regarding return codes. I compressed down my code to as little as possible to show my point. Here is the code block:

```
def main():
    try:
        while True:
            print(".")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Catch")
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Obviously you would never use code like this, I mean, it just print out infinite `.` and why would you want that?

That is not the point however, the point is that when I terminate this program it not only does **NOT** print `Catch` but it returns an exit code of -1!

Two questions based on that:

1. Why does the try catch block not work?
2. What can I use to catch this kind of error?

**EDIT**

Thank you for all your comments so far, a few notes and and a new question:

- My OS is Windows 10.
- I use Pycharm as my IDE, I use CTRL-SHIFT-F10 to
  run the program and CTRL-F2 to close it, which emulates the "run" and
  "terminate" buttons on the top right, my experience is that this
  counts as a keyboard interrupt.
- Pycharm displays the exit code after running code with configurations.

So is the IDE close no longer counting as a keyboard inturrupt? If so, does anybody know how to configure it to do so? Or do I really just need to run the script from the terminal?

Comment: Did you actually interrupt the program in a way that generates a KeyboardInterrupt? It doesn't sound like it. (The usual way to generate a KeyboardInterrupt would be Ctrl-C.)

Comment: How exactly did you terminate the program?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using and how are you terminating the program? Because in my computer it DOES print "Catch" and with no error code of -1.

Comment: Please specify your OS. And one more question: how you terminate your program? I checked your code and it work.

Comment: How did you determine that the exit code was -1?

Comment: These don't appear to be [documented shortcuts of PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/ctrl.html). Did you set them up yourself? If so, exactly what did you configure Ctrl-F2 to do?

Comment: I didn't set up the shortcuts no... seem to be the default for me, I get them when hovering over the "play" and "stop" buttons.